# Is this sentence grammatically correct? "there isn't a"

Tags: grammar, negation

I want to know whether this sentence is valid or not which I was studying for my third language in Duolingo and got a wrong answer.
The general format of the sentence is:

> "There isn't a/an `<some noun>` in the `<some place>`"

Example:

> There isn't a cow in the zoo.

The suggestions are:

- There aren't any cows in the zoo.
- There are no cows in the zoo.

By the way, I'm familiar with both suggestions, though more curious about my made-up first sentence from the first example. ("There isn't a cow in the zoo.")

Thanks for the answers in advance.

Comment: The construction *There isn't/wasn't a/an <some noun> in the <some place>* is a well-established usage. It's not confined to complaining about the *lack* of something wanted - one very common version is ***There wasn't a dry eye in the house***, where "the house" is (literally or figuratively) a theatre or cinema that's just presented something particularly emotionally stirring (bringing poignant tears to the eyes of a fully-engaged audience). That's usually considered a *good* thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is a valid English sentence, though the suggested versions are more natural ways of expressing the idea that zoos don't normally keep domestic animals such as cows.

We would use a sentence like that to say that there is a lack of something that we need and should have supplies of.

> I need to make sandwiches, but there isn't a loaf of bread in the house!

@FumbleFingers gives another example of a context where this construction is used.

Comment: +1. Another context where we might say "There isn't a cow in the zoo" is in rebutting a suggestion that there *is* one.